# Polynomials, given roots

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> **4** The cubic equation $x^3-2x^2+3x+4=0$ has roots $\alpha,\beta,\gamma.$
>
> **(I)** Write down the values of $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$, $\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha$, and $\alpha\beta\gamma$.
>
> The cubic equation $x^3+px^2+10x+q=0$, where $p$ and $q$ are constants, has roots $\alpha+1$, $\beta+1$, $\gamma+1$.
>
> **(II)** Find the value of $p$. $\color{gray}{-(\overbrace{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}+3)}$
>
> **(III)** Find the value of $q$.

In **4.II**, I know you need to use the sum of the roots given so you'd get what I have written (in gray), but how can you use $-b/a$ if you have "p" as your b term?

Comment: Are you actually in an exam?

Comment: Nope haha, It's a sheet that was given to me ages ago.

Comment: What's the relevance of $-b/a$? FWIW, the answer for `4.(ii)` marked on the sheet is correct: since it's a monic polynomial (the leading coefficient is 1), $p$ is simply the sum of the roots.

Comment: I wrote that but I need to use it to find p which apparently equals -5

Comment: Oops! That should be $-p$ is the sum of the roots; sorry about that. Are you supposed to use the $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ from `4.(i)` in parts `(ii)` and `(iii)`?

Comment: $p=-((\alpha+1)+(\beta+1)+(\gamma+1))=-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)-3$, but $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=2$ because we are told $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are the roots of $x^3-2x^2+3x+4$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ of degree $3$ has roots $α,β,γ$, then $g(x)=f(x-1)$ has roots $α+1,β+1,γ+1$. Note that
$$
p(x)=c_3(x-α)(x-β)(x-γ)
$$
relating coefficients and elementary symmetric polynomials in the roots.

See also the root laws of Viete.