# Polynomial Question Help

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the equation $2x^{3}+3x+3=0$ and have been told to substitute in $x=u+2$ which gives $2u^{3}+12u^{2}+27u+25$. I am the  told to work out the value of ${1\over \alpha+1} + {1\over \beta+1} + {1\over \gamma+1}$ and apparently you can get $y={1\over u}$ but I don't see how you can get this? I know you then sub this into the equation once re-arranged to $y$ and use ${-b\over a}$ but don't see how you get the $y={1\over u}$? Any Ideas?

Comment: what are $\alpha,\beta,\gamma?$

Comment: Roots of the equation

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write the sum ${1\over \alpha+1} + {1\over \beta+1} + {1\over \gamma+1}$ with a common denominator. Then use the fact that you know the sum of the roots, the sum of the product of the roots two at a time, and the product of the roots.

PS this answer [Polynomials, given roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212832/polynomials-given-roots) to another question you asked may help too.

Comment: I was going to do that but it just takes too long, the teacher used another way

Answer (score 1):

I am confused by the question.

If the roots of $2x^3+3x+3=0$ are $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and you put $u=x+1$ to obtain $$2(u-1)^3+3(u-1)+3=2u^3-6u^2+9u-2=0$$The roots of this equation are $u=\alpha+1, \beta+1, \gamma+1$ by construction.

Now set $y=\frac 1u$ so that $\frac 2{y^3}-\frac 6{y^2}+\frac 9y-2=0$ and multiply through by $-y^3$ to obtain $$2y^3-9y^2+6y-2=0$$

The roots of this are $y=\frac 1{\alpha+1}, \frac 1{\beta+1}, \frac 1{\gamma+1}$ and the sum of the roots is obtained using Vieta's relations in the usual way (deriving the sum of the roots from the coefficients).

That would be a method of proceeding compatible with some, but not all, of what you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve it this way:

$$\frac{1}{\alpha+1}+\frac{1}{\beta+1}+\frac{1}{\gamma+1}=\frac{(1+\beta+\gamma+\beta\gamma)+(1+\alpha+\gamma+\alpha\gamma)+(1+\beta+\alpha+\beta\alpha)}{(1+\beta+\gamma+\beta\gamma)(\alpha+1)}$$
$$=\frac{3+2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)}{1+(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)+\alpha\beta\gamma}$$

Now, you know the values of $(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)$, $(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)$ and $\alpha\beta\gamma$ from your equation. Just substitute.